# React/Vanilla JavaScript: Is there a property on the event object when using onChange event yielding the line or row of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a textarea component I made in React:

```
<Textbox
 as="textarea"
 type="text"
 placeholder="Variable Types"
 aria-rowindex={currentRow}
 rows="6"
 cols="60"
 maxLength = "100"
 value={variableTypeName}
 onPaste={e => handlePaster(e)}
 onChange={e => handleChange(e)} >
</Textbox>
```

[image]

It has line line numbers, and I'd like to find the property (if it exists) to give me the current line number or row.

I consoled the `event` object but it's pretty huge!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sets the line numbers. Must be a plugin or something - if you split on `\n` you should know what lines you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably split the lines, then go through .map to check line by line.

```js
const text = `Hello!! 
I am on a new line! 
and this is the third line`


let lines = text.split('\n');

console.log(lines.map( (item,index) => `${index+1} - ${item}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like provided in the comment section, I was trying the option of the '\n'.

I'm not aware of a property on the Event. But if split on '\n' and then do a search on each index to see if the fault is occurring there then you know the line number with your index.